# JAXP IllegalAnnotationExceptions

Tags: java, xml, debugging, xerces, jaxp

JAXP gives me this error

```
10 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
```

Is there any way of finding out where these 10 errors are? If I quote some of my code I can get it down to 7 errors, but that is the most idiotic way of debugging...

Can I register some ErrorHandler like you can do with DOM?

My code looks like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbFactory.setNamespaceAware( true);
dbFactory.setValidating(true);
dbFactory.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
dBuilder.setErrorHandler(logger);
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
JAXBContext jc= JAXBContext.newInstance(Config.class); // Here exception is thrown
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Config config =  (Config) u.unmarshal(doc);
```

EDIT:

Here is the stack trace, but it doesn't really tell my where the errors are.

> Message: 10 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(Unknown Source)
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(Unknown Source)
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.(Unknown Source)
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)

Comment: Your JAXB implementation is what is throwing the `IllegalAnnotationException`.  You are not getting any sort of stack trace?

Comment: See edit: it only gives me some aggregated exception for all of the 10 errors